# TypeError: The view function for ' ' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: flask

I am trying to learn flask API with basic user CRUD operations on mysql database. My fetch all users is working perfect. But with same DB creating user is giving TypeError

This is my create user endpoint. For db connection I am using flask-mysqldb

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    try:
        if not request.is_json:
            return jsonify({"message": "Bad Request: Request body must be JSON ☠️ "}), 400
        else:
            data = request.get_json()
            
            fname = data.get('first_name')
            lname = data.get('last_name')
            gender = data.get('gender')
            email = data.get('email')
            phone = data.get('phone')
            country_code = data.get('country_code')
            
            
            if fname and lname and email and gender and phone and country_code:
                conn = mysql.connect()
                cur = conn.cursor()


                cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, gender, email, phone_number, phone_country_code) VALUES (%s,%s,%c,%s,%s,%s) """.format(fname, lname, gender, email, phone_number, country_code))
                conn.commit()
          
                
                cur.close()
                conn.close()
                return jsonify({"message": "User created successfully  " }), 200
            else:
                return jsonify({"message": "Some data is missing  "}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I am getting JSON data inside if statement which is am passing through postman

```
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "gender" : "M",
    "email" : "john@fakedoe.com",
    "phone" : "9876543210",
    "country_code" : "UK"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

on debug, I found the issue was with sql query. We could solve this TypeError issue by simply changing SQL query format.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users ( fname, lname, gender, email, phone_number, phone_country_code)
VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (fname, lname, gender, email, phone, country_code))

conn.commit()
```

Hope this help whoever came across this issue.